# NativeScript: I can't connect to my local .NET Core API

Tags: android, asp.net-core, nativescript, asp.net-core-webapi

I keep getting the following error when trying to connect to my .NET Core API. I don't know why it happens, all tutorials I watched or other posts I read didn't help me at all.

```
JS: ERROR {
JS:   "headers": {
JS:     "normalizedNames": {},
JS:     "lazyUpdate": null,
JS:     "headers": {}
JS:   },
JS:   "status": 0,
JS:   "statusText": "Unknown Error",
JS:   "url": "http://10.0.2.2:44362/api/PlayDay/AllPlayDays",
JS:   "ok": false,
JS:   "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
JS:   "message": "Http failure response for http://10.0.2.2:44362/api/PlayDay/AllPlayDays: 0 Unknown Error",
JS:   "error": {
JS:     "originalStack": "Error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset\n    at new ZoneAwareError (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.AVDKfrontend/files/app/vendor.js:91668:33)\n    at onRequestComplete (fifile:///data/data/org.nativescript.AVDKfrontend/files/app/vendor.js:97326:34)\n    at Object.onComplete (file:///node_modules\@nativescript\core\http\http-request\http-request.js:43:0)"
JS:   }
JS: }
```

This is my service:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class PlayDayService {

    private readonly API = 'http://10.0.2.2:44362/';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getPlayDays() {
        let httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders(
            {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })}
            
        return this.http.get(this.API + 'api/PlayDay/AllPlayDays', httpOptions);
    }

}
```

I do allow Internet. It seems to always time out...

Comment: likely you need to set cleartextTrafficPermitted for `10.0.2.2`... and if so, it's a dupe... while JS & ZoneAwareError seems to be Angular - in this case it's also a dupe. please search before asking.

Comment: I did set that, didn't help :/

Comment: Can you access that API in Chrome on device?

Comment: No I can’t the page keeps loading

Comment: Well, then you should probably fix the API in the first place. Does it load on a computer? Because if it does, the wired and wireless network segments might not be properly bridged (common DSL router setting).

Comment: It does load on my computer, yes. I’ll thanks for the comment, I’ll check it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem myself.
We're using conveyor by keyoti to access the api in dev and my main problem was that my firewall rule was wrong. Adjusted as per Keyoti's instruction and I was able to access the api via browser.

Would've commentent but my rep. is too low.